# Audio ends, reshuffle variable and play another audio

Tags: javascript, html

I use this script on a Play button, when clicked it starts a randomized audio, when clicked again the audio stops.

My issue is, if I don't click to stop the song, the song will end and it will restart - I want to make it so that when the song ends, it will reshuffle the variable and acquire a new song, instead of repeating the first one.

```
var sounds = [
    "sounds/royksopp.mp3",
    "sounds/9thwonder.mp3",
    "sounds/thisbeat.mp3",
    "sounds/mosdef.mp3",
    "sounds/bewater.mp3",
    "sounds/boutdre.mp3",
    "sounds/masterflash.mp3",
    "sounds/2ep.mp3",
    "sounds/drewestcoast.mp3",
    "sounds/poetry.mp3",
    "sounds/mfdoom.mp3",
    "sounds/imnot.mp3",
    "sounds/jamba.mp3",
    "sounds/meetyour.mp3",
    "sounds/popyacork.mp3",
    "sounds/dreams.mp3",
    "sounds/unders.mp3",
    "sounds/oizo.mp3", ];

function Start(audioFile) {
    srcAudio = sounds[Math.floor(Math.random()*sounds.length)];
    var audie = document.getElementById("myAudio");
    audie.addEventListener('ended', function() {
        this.currentTime = 0;
        this.play();
        }, false);

    $(audie).animate({volume: 0.9}, 0);
    audie.src = srcAudio;
    audie.play();

}

function Stop(audioFile) {
    var audie = document.getElementById("myAudio");
    $(audie).animate({volume: 0}, 400);
}
```

I think I have to change something on `audie.src = srcAudio;`?

You can check the Play button here: https://www.vtxfactory.org/

---

CODE UPDATED:
I've added:

```
    var sounds = [
        "sounds/royksopp.mp3",
        "sounds/9thwonder.mp3",
        "sounds/thisbeat.mp3",
        "sounds/mosdef.mp3",
        "sounds/bewater.mp3",
        "sounds/boutdre.mp3",
        "sounds/masterflash.mp3",
        "sounds/2ep.mp3",
        "sounds/drewestcoast.mp3",
        "sounds/poetry.mp3",
        "sounds/mfdoom.mp3",
        "sounds/imnot.mp3",
        "sounds/jamba.mp3",
        "sounds/meetyour.mp3",
        "sounds/popyacork.mp3",
        "sounds/dreams.mp3",
        "sounds/unders.mp3",
        "sounds/oizo.mp3", ];

    function Start(audioFile) {
        srcAudio = sounds[Math.floor(Math.random()*sounds.length)];
        var audie = document.getElementById("myAudio");
        audie.addEventListener('ended', function() {
     this.currentTime = 0;
     if(isPlaying)
     {
        this.src = sounds[Math.floor(Math.random()*sounds.length)];
        this.play();
     }
}, false);

                $(audie).animate({volume: 0.9}, 0);
                audie.src = srcAudio;
                audie.play();

          }

    function Stop(audioFile) {
        var audie = document.getElementById("myAudio");

                $(audie).animate({volume: 0}, 400);

          }
```

And now the audio stops when comes to the end. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your first code would be fine if you just set a new src after previous song ended.

```
function Start(audioFile) {
    srcAudio = sounds[Math.floor(Math.random()*sounds.length)];
    var audie = document.getElementById("myAudio");
    audie.addEventListener('ended', function() {
        this.currentTime = 0;
        this.src = sounds[Math.floor(Math.random()*sounds.length)];
        this.play();
        }, false);

    $(audie).animate({volume: 0.9}, 0);
    audie.src = srcAudio;
    audie.play();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a toggle variable **isPlaying = true** on Start() and **isPlaying = false** on Stop().

So if that variable is true( User still wants to listen ) add in the ended listener something like:

```
audie.addEventListener('ended', function() {
     this.currentTime = 0;
     if(isPlaying)
     {
        this.src = sounds[Math.floor(Math.random()*sounds.length)];
        this.play();
     }
}, false);
```

Comment: I've updated my post with the answer to you, so it stays formated.